# Divison of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I need to find m and n , ($m,n\in R$ ) so that 
      $P(x)=x^m + x^{m-1} + \dots+x+1$
is divisible by     $Q(x)=x^n + x^{n-1} + \dots+x+1$ 
 I have no clue what to do here except that  $m>n$ and $n|m$.
What should the values of $m$ and $n$ be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : if you multiply both polynomials by $X-1$ you get respectively $X^{n+1}-1$ and $X^{m+1}-1$. Now look at the complex roots of these, they are pretty well-known.

Comment: Don't I get $\frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$   and $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ but still don't know how can that help me ?

Comment: Q divides P if and only if $X^{n+1}-1$ divides $X^{m+1}-1$, and since these polynomials have simple roots over $\mathbb{C}$ this is equivalent to: "all the roots of  $X^{n+1}-1$ are also roots of $X^{m+1}-1$".

Comment: Which is the case exactly when n+1 divides m+1.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1$ is a root neither of $P$ nor of $Q$, this is the same as asking when $x^{m+1}-1$ divides $x^{n+1}-1$. It's well known that
$$
x^k-1=\prod_{d\mid k}\Phi_d(x)
$$
where $\Phi_d(x)$ is the [*$d$-th cyclotomic polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), that is, the product
$$
\Phi_d(x)=\prod_{\zeta}(x-\zeta)
$$
where the product runs over the *primitive* $d$-th roots of unity. For instance, $$
\Phi_1(x)=x-1,\quad
\Phi_2(x)=x+1,\quad
\Phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1,\quad
\Phi_4(x)=x^2+1
$$
and each $\Phi_d(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now put everything together.

> The necessary and sufficient condition is $(m+1)\mid(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

If $P(x) = k(x)Q(x)$ then $P(x)(x-1)=k(x)Q(x)(x-1)$ so $$x^{m+1}-1 = k(x)(x^{n+1}-1)$$
and this is well know it is true exactly when $n+1\mid m+1$.

---

**Anyway you can prove this statement pretty easly.**

If $$1+x+...+x^n\mid 1+...+x^m$$  then this is true for all integers so specially for $x=1$ and thus $n+1\mid m+1$.

And vice versa. Write $a=m+1$ and $b=n+1$ then $a=lb$ so $$x^a-1 = (x^b)^l-1=(x^b-1)((x^b)^{l-1}+...+x^b+1)$$ and we are done.